# how can I solve this problem is it from the functions or modules?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python so I would be happy if you help me . Here is the code

```
final_url = 'https://www.worlddata.info/america/chile/index.php'
response = requests.get(final_url)
str_response = response.text
lst = re.findall(r"population:</a>\S{1,}</div>", str_response)
print (lst)
```

I did it level by level but at the end when I run the code the list is empty

Comment: The code you posted does not run. It misses `re` and `requests` imports. I agree that it's obvious there, but even so, do always post a code that we can just copy/paste and run, it also remove the ambiguity of what is `requests` and `re` there (an import ? an object behaving like the import ? ... ?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `findall()` cannot find any matches for your regex inside `str_response`.
This could mean that your regex isn't written in the right way and/or the response text really doesn't contain the text you're looking for.

You can test your regex at a number of different sites, I personally use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, you just need correct regexp:

instead

```
r"population:</a>\S{1,}</div>"
```

use

```
r"Population:</a>\S{1,}</div>"
```

Comment: what is the difference ? I can not find it? where did I go wrong?

Comment: In the link you posted, there's 'Population', not 'population'. If you want the regex to ignore the case (which is _a_ solution, tho the above one is a lot easier to add), you need to add an appropriate regex flag: [regex flags](https://pynative.com/python-regex-flags/)